Use S3 as the source to create iceberg tables
I am currently working on a small setup where I have a basic setup of iceberg, trino, hive metastore and s3.
I am able to create iceberg tables in s3 using the trino CLI.
Now, I would like to use a sample parquet file that's stored in s3 and create iceberg tables using it's data. I am unable to figure out what kind of config or trino command that I need to pass in order to use the parquet file in s3 as my source.
Any help on this would be great. TIA!
my-trino.yaml
image:
  tag: "463"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
server:
  workers: 2
  config:
    properties:
      # S3 configurations
      "fs.s3.aws.credentials.provider": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider"
      "fs.s3.endpoint": "s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
      "fs.s3.region": "us-west-1"
      "fs.s3.use-instance-credentials": "false"
      "fs.s3.use-web-identity-token-credentials-provider": "true"
      "fs.s3.path-style-access": "true"
      # Iceberg configurations
      "iceberg.max-splits-per-scan": "1"
      # Discovery configurations
      "discovery.uri": "http://trino-coordinator:8080"
serviceAccount:
  create: false
  name: trino-service-account
coordinator:
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    port: 8080
    name: trino-coordinator
  jvm:
    maxHeapSize: "3G"
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: "4Gi"
      cpu: "2"
    requests:
      memory: "2Gi"
      cpu: "1"
worker:
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    name: trino-worker
  jvm:
    maxHeapSize: "3G"
    -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError: ""
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError: ""
    -XX:HeapDumpPath: "/tmp/dump.hprof"
  config:
    discovery.uri: "http://trino-coordinator:8080"
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: "4Gi"
      cpu: "2"
    requests:
      memory: "2Gi"
      cpu: "1"
catalogs:
  iceberg: |-
    connector.name=iceberg
    hive.metastore.uri=thrift://hivems-hive-metastore.arvind.svc.cluster.local:9083
    iceberg.catalog.type=hive_metastore
    s3.aws-access-key=******
    s3.aws-secret-key=******
    s3.path-style-access=true
    fs.native-s3.enabled=true
    iceberg.unique-table-location=true
  hive: |-
    connector.name=hive
    hive.metastore.uri=thrift://hivems-hive-metastore.arvind.svc.cluster.local:9083
    hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled=true

my-values.yaml
# The base hadoop image to use for all components.
# See this repo for image build details: https://github.com/Comcast/kube-yarn/tree/master/image
postgresql:
  postgresqlUsername: hive
  postgresqlPassword: hive
  postgresqlDatabase: metastore

  initdbScriptsConfigMap: hive-metastore-postgresql-init
image:
  repository: jboothomas/hive-metastore-s3
  tag: v6
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

resources: {}
conf:
  hiveSite:
    hive_metastore_uris: thrift://hivems-hive-metastore:9083
    fs.s3a.access.key: *******
    fs.s3a.secret.key: *******
    hive.metastore.warehouse.dir: s3a://my-iceberg-trino-bucket/iceberg-warehouse
    fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled: false


It looks like you have provided a configuration file for setting up Trino with specific settings for S3, Iceberg, and other related components. Here are a few observations and suggestions based on the provided configuration:
S3 Configuration:
The fs.s3.region is set to us-west-1, but the fs.s3.endpoint is s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com. Ensure that the region and endpoint are consistent to avoid any potential issues.
The fs.s3.aws.credentials.provider is set to use WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider, which is suitable for environments like Kubernetes where IAM roles for service accounts are used.
Iceberg Configuration:
The iceberg.max-splits-per-scan is set to "1", which might be useful for controlling the number of splits per scan operation, potentially optimizing performance for specific workloads.
Service Account:
The service account creation is disabled (create: false), and a specific service account name (trino-service-account) is provided. Ensure that this service account exists and has the necessary permissions.
Coordinator and Worker Configuration:
Both the coordinator and worker JVM settings include options to handle out-of-memory errors and heap dumps, which is good for debugging.
Resource limits and requests are defined for both memory and CPU, ensuring that the pods have the necessary resources allocated.
Catalogs Configuration:
The Iceberg and Hive catalogs are configured with necessary details like the metastore URI and S3 credentials. Ensure that the credentials (s3.aws-access-key and s3.aws-secret-key) are securely managed and not exposed.
PostgreSQL Configuration:
The PostgreSQL settings for the Hive metastore include the username, password, and database name. Ensure that these credentials are correct and that the database is properly initialized using the provided init scripts.
Image and Resources:
The image for the Hive metastore is specified along with the pull policy. Ensure that the image is available and accessible.
Additional Configuration:
The hiveSite configuration includes settings for the Hive metastore URIs, S3 access keys, and the warehouse directory. Ensure that these settings are correct and that the S3 bucket is properly configured.
Overall, the configuration seems well-structured for deploying Trino with Iceberg and Hive on a Kubernetes cluster. Make sure to validate all the settings and test the deployment in a staging environment before moving to production
